# CSS give same width to vertically aligned elements not sharing common parent?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, flexbox, alignment

In the following figure, I'd like to make all the red boxes the width of the biggest red box, can I do it with this type of layout, or would I have to make two separate columns so that the red boxes could share a common parent? Or maybe use grid? [image]

Comment: @TemaniAfif Simple, yet effective. I've seen some people ASCII art their entire layout, but I don't have that kind of talent.

Comment: Please.  Give us your code.  You already have given us the output.  With your code, you will have more chances to have your problem solved.

Comment: it's not simple and not effective. We don't need such screenshot, we need the code that product the output inside the screenshot. Your question will simply get closed soon https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask / https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the right way to show it with paint and say I want it, as other friends say. Please share the codes you're trying next time.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin:auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.text {
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.text p {
  border: 3px solid red;
  flex-basis: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">
    <label>text1</label>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <label>text2</label>
    <p>G</p>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <label>text3</label>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas, officia?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```